# if UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary allowsediting NO

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

When I use allowsEditing = NO on the camera it works fine.

Works:

```
if( [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
  if(imagePicker == nil) imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
   imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
   imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;

  [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

But if I try to put it on the photo library I still get allowsEditing YES.

Don't work:

```
if( [UIImagePickerController UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
{
  if(imagePicker == nil) imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
   imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
   imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;

  [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.delegate = self;
```

Comment: I already have this since it is working as I want when it is in cameramode.

Comment: I've been starring to long at the code. I looked at the wrong method. Everything works great. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @hugocarlmartin anytime buddy :)